# Prevent Google maps infowindow from closing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

If certain conditions are met when an infoWindow is closed, I want to prevent the default close event that is fired. Is it possible to achieve that? I tried a number of things like:

1. Stopping event propagation
2. returning false from the callback method
3. there aren't any methods/properties exposed by the infoWindow either that prevent close.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The InfoWindow doesn't really provide a way to step event propagation. I don't know if it could work for you, but there is an [InfoBox Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox) that does give you a great deal more of control oven its behavior. Specific to your question, the `InfoBoxOptions`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/docs/reference.html) object includes the property:

`enableEventPropagation`, a boolean, that will allow you to control whether the `InfoBox` will: propagate mousedown, click, dblclick, and contextmenu events in the InfoBox (default is false to mimic the behavior of a `google.maps.InfoWindow`). Set this property to true if the InfoBox is being used as a map label. **iPhone note:** This property setting has no effect; events are always propagated.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is catch the `closeclick` event which leads you nowhere.

I have hacked something together once, for a one-off solution, that might or might not work for you: I have identified a way to get to the x-mark that the user clicks to close, and removed that. The user can't close the infoWindow. At all. You still can, by calling .close().

**WARNING! THIS IS A HACK**

```
var a=document.getElementById('map_canvas');
var b=a.getElementsByTagName('img');
var i, j=b.length;
for (i=0; i<j; i++) {
  if(b[i].src.match('imgs8.png')){
    if(b[i].style.left=='-18px') {
      c=b[i].parentElement.parentElement;
      console.log(c);
      if(c.innerText.match("Map data")) {
        console.log('no');
      } else {
        b[i].parentElement.removeChild(b[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now. If you store a reference to the [x] mark, you could even turn it on and off at will.

**EDIT:**

[A demonstration of this hack](http://stimulus.hk/demos/iwOnOff.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could always listen for the close event and then throw a javascript error to keep it from closing. Ex:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(my_infoWindow, 'closeclick', function(e){
    // Throw an error to stop the close
    throw "stop close";
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, "e" is undefined