# Google Maps infowindow closeclick event (function parameter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, overlay, infowindow

My web application uses the following popup-overlay plugin to show profile content in a popup on the screen:
http://vast-eng.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/

My problem is related to a Google Map - marker infowindow that I use within the popup window.
When I try to close the infowindow, the popup disappears as well.
This is wrong! I don't immediately see why it is doing this.
If I don't find a solution, I could disable or hide the X, but I prefer not to do this.

The "where" section in the following link shows you the problem:
http://www.zwoop.be/dev/#list/bars/1

**Edit** 
The event parameter returns "undefined" for the following event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(self.marker.infowindow, "closeclick", function(e)
    {
        console.log(e); 
    });
```

Thanks

[image]

**Edit2** 
Here is a quick fiddle that illustrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/462HF/

Comment: I believe the undefined is correct. What would you expect there? Try to create a jsfiddle with a popup, a map and an infowindow, then we might be able to help further.

Comment: I had hoped to prevent event bubbling to parent elements with stopPropagation.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/462HF/

Comment: Wow that is strange. Can't yet figure out why this happens...

Comment: Nasty problem, pretty annoying that is. Btw, I noticed that I passed "map" as argument to the initialize function in the fiddle. That's obviously a mistake. I quickly fabricated the fiddle, but the problem remains the same. The application I'm building is based on backbone.js.

Comment: Very similar problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683067/prevent-google-maps-infowindow-from-closing)

Comment: I found this post too, but the way the event propagates to the popup window is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Hmm, so should I conclude that there is no viable fix for this particular situation?

Comment: You might want to create a bounty for that. I have tried a few things but no luck to get this fixed by now on my side.

Comment: Ok, thanks @MrUpsidown I'll leave it pending for a few days and create the bounty as you suggest.

Comment: Interesting: If you close infowindow using method close(), popup window and map stay opened. Put `setTimeout(function() { infowindow.close(); }, 5000);`, into marker `click` handler, open infowindow and wait.

Comment: I believe that applying close() will work. However, I need the popup to stay open when the user wants to close the infobox for whatever reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur function in the popup overlay plugin is getting called when you click the 'X' in the infoWindow on the google map, that is why the entire popup is closing.  Below is the code in the jquery.popupoverlay.js file:

```
if (options.blur) {
            blurhandler = function (e) {
                if (!$(e.target).parents().andSelf().is('#' + el.id)) {
                    methods.hide(el);
                }
            };
        }
```

The 'X' is an image, and its `parents()`only go back to the InfoWindow div, but not the popup div.  Therefore, it will call `methods.hide(el)` and close the popup.

There is probably a better way of determining if it was clicked, but changing it to the following works.  It just checks the target's img source:

```
if (options.blur) {
            blurhandler = function (e) {
                if (!$(e.target).parents().andSelf().is('#' + el.id) ) {
                    if(!($(e.target).attr('src') === 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png'))
                        methods.hide(el);
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I have followed your guideline, and put a condition on the tag. No img should trigger the hide, and I'm not sure if the img source will be the same forever. `if(!($(e.target).prop("tagName") === 'IMG'))` You did solve my problem, so thanks for that!